# Generics e interface Comparable

Tags: java, interface, genéricos

No método `public static <T extends Comparable <T>> T max(List <T> list){}` como o tipo T pode ser estendido pela interface comparable? Se T é um tipo de referência (classe).

Comment: Não sei se entendi qual é a dúvida. Você está achando que não pode? Por que acha isto? `T` não é uma classe. Talvez isso já faça toda diferença. `T` será substituído por um tipo, pode ser uma classe, mas no futuro poderá ser um tipo por valor. Talvez o problema seja a péssima palavra escolhida por java, ali não está estendendo nada, está dizendo que `T` tem que ser do tipo `Comparable<T>`, só isso.

Comment: O `T` entre `< >` indica um tipo genérico (ou seja, pode ter um tipo qualquer ali). O `extends` serve para restringir o tipo que `T` pode ser - no caso, só pode ser algum que seja um sub-tipo de `Comparable<T>`. Eu sugiro dar uma lida [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) para entender melhor (mas leia o tutorial todo também, ajudará a entender generics como um todo)